# does it template tag in django execute twice?

Tags: django-templates, django-custom-tags

If I put in django `template.html` this code

`<p>{% if some_custom_template %} {%some_custom_template%} {% else %} nothing {% endif %}</p>`

will `some_custom_template` executed twice? Or `some_custom_template` result is buffered?

If `some_custom_template` is executed twice, how I can save first result in some *template variable*?

Comment: In test case, `some_custom_template` is just `return 5`. In production, it was a db-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it will be executed twice, but it depends on what `some_custom_template` actually is. But regardless, you can cache it using the [`with` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#with)

```
{% with cached_template=some_custom_template %}</p>
    <p>
       {% if cached_template %}
         {{ cached_template }}
       {% else %}
          nothing
       {% endif %}
    </p>
{% endwith %}
```

---

Edit: With context, you are using a custom **`template_tag`**, which is very different. Yes they are generated every time you call them, and they cannot be cached.

What would be better is to move the logic of what to display into the template tag and remove the `if/then/else` in the template, like so:

```
@simple_tag(name='unread_notification_count', takes_context=True)
def unread_notification_count(context):
  if some_check:
    return some_value
  else:
    return "nothing"
```

Then in the template just have the template tag call:

```
<p>{% unread_notification_count %}</p>
```

Comment: Tested - fail. This template will raise `TemplateSyntaxError - Invalid block tag: 'cached_template', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'`, I think, because `{% cached_template %}` should be `{{ cached_template }}`. Both variants doesn's work. Django 1.6.5.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the code straight from the question, `{{ cached_template }}` should work, what happens when you try that?

Comment: `{% with cached_template=some_custom_template %}` doesn't triggering the templatetags py file, and `cached_template` always None

Comment: Hang on, what exactly is `some_custom_template`? Is it a variable, template_tag?

Comment: I have `@register.simple_tag(name='unread_notification_count', takes_context=True)
def unread_notification_count(context):` in `templatetags` folder, and `{% unread_notification_count %}` in html. As `{% unread_notification_count %}` it's working fine.

Comment: I've updated the answer to answer the actual problem

Comment: You mean, `return some_value` should return html string? Ok.

Comment: Well, a string. It doesn't need to be HTML. Just return the value.